# Canon MX420 has stopped printing

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon

My Canon MX420 was printing and will not do so now.
The printer screen says "wait-processing" and then nothing happens.
I have looked for solutions online without success.

sorry..new to this. I see nothing that says  so hope this is the right place.

I am running ubuntu 12.04.5 LT6 64 bit. the printer was working. now, when I send a file to the printer, the PRINTER SCREEN says

> processing...Please wait momentarily

(which it usually does when receiving a file).
the printer then shuts off instead of printing and returns to its resting screen.
thank you for your patience

I send a file by using either ctrl P or by hitting the printer button...both yield the same result
AND
JUST TESTED PRINTER WITH NETBOOK USING WINDOWS..it works, so the problem is with my linux/ubuntu
thx...hoping for help soon...

Comment: Please describe exactly what printer model and manufacturer you have, what you're using to print and in what exact context that "wait-processing" message appears (a screenshot may help).

Comment: canon MX420 I am running ubuntu 12.04.5. on a Dell Latitude E5510

Comment: In the future, please [edit] your question, if you want to add new information. It's much  better to have all the relevant info in one place than search for them. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons. I would still like to know, what application you're using to print and where and under what circumstances the mentioned message appears.

Comment: How do you "send a file to the printer"?